# JavaScript: function fires in different order

Tags: javascript, events

I don't understand why function `alert()` fires before setting style to `indicator` in this code:

**JavaScript:**

```
var MyClass = function()
{
  th       = this;
  th.func  = function(){alert('yes');};
  th.Click = function(){
    document.getElementById('indicator').style.color = "#0f0";
    document.getElementById('indicator').innerHTML = "YES";
    th.func();     // here it fires before above style changing
  };
  th.Start = function()
  {
    var a  = document.getElementById('button1');
    a.addEventListener('click', th.Click, false);
  };
  th.Init  = function()
  {
    th.Start();
  };
}
var a = new MyClass().Init();
```

**Html:**

```
<button id='button1'>Click Me</button>
<div id='indicator' style='color:#f00'>NO</div>
```

---

I want it to fire **after**.

Comment: It fires after, but what you experience is "thread blocking". The alert() will stop every action from your browser on the current page. So it also blocks the redrawing of the content. You can check by using non-blocking call to alert like `window.setTimeout(th.func, 0);`

Comment: @devnull69, so if it will be different function, for example `GET()` request instead of `alert()`, it will act in normal order?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but only for asynchronous methods. For every synchronous one, you'd see the change only afterwards (in idle mode) if you don't use `setTimeout` for example

Comment: @devnull69 How can I do it without using `setTimeout()`? I mean, do anything (asynchronous/synchronous), but only after setting style, in the same function.. If it's not possible to do in same function, then what will be the good example of doing so?

Comment: It's the nature of single threaded Javascript. You can only make sure that the view updates if the thread has time to do it. As long as your code runs without a break (i.e. asnychronouos method call or some user interaction) it just won't have the time to do it.

Comment: @devnull69 Thank you! cheers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That is because of the **Single Threaded Nature of the Javascript**. The alert / modal window actually stops everything else from running until it is dismissed.

That includes the changing of color. Javascript actually says hey browser start changing colors and moves on but as it hits an alert the changing of colors or whatever processes that happen will be paused and it will not start continuing again until the modal window aka alert is dismissed. A workaround might be to do something like this: [codepen](http://codepen.io/summersoldier/pen/BRaEOM)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id='button1'>Click Me</button>
        <div id='indicator' style='color:#f00'>NO</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var MyClass = function() {
         th             = this;
         th.func  = function() { window.alert('yes'); };
         th.Click = function() {
             document.getElementById('indicator').style.color = "#0f0";
             document.getElementById('indicator').innerHTML = "YES";
             // The setTimeout fix
             // ====
             setTimeout(th.func, 100);
         };
         th.Start = function()
         {
             var a  = document.getElementById('button1');
             a.addEventListener('click', th.Click, false);
         };
         th.Init  = function()
         {
             th.Start();
         };
        }
        var a = new MyClass().Init();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ow ok. Last question: For example, I have veeery slow machine (or very loaded) and we have here not only style changing, but big big function before timeout and I set timeout to `1`, will it fire after too even in these conditions?

Comment: a setTimeout code will always be executed in the next processor cycle(tick) no matter what. Take an example: `setTimeout(() => { alert("Hi"); }, 0);
alert("Hello!");` Here actually the alert of "Hi" should work first since we have to wait 0s, but "Hello!" works first

Comment: Yeah, I did a loop and it worked fine, Thank You for your help! ;))